# how to use split method for my string

Tags: java

I have tried to split a string, but I couldn't get the expected output. See below is code:

```
String line="com.mgnt.util.DateTimeTokenizer.setEndDateTimeValues=90027";
String[] str=line.split("\\.(?=[^.]+\\.[^.]+$)");
for(int i=0;i<=str.length-1;i++)
{
    System.out.println(str[i]);
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
com.mgnt.util
DateTimeTokenizer.setEndDateTimeValues=90027
```

It displayed correct output for the above split method. But, My expectation is like below,

```
com.mgnt.util
DateTimeTokenizer
setEndDateTimeValues
90027
```

I don't know how to use regex to getting the above expected output.
Share your ideas If you know.

Comment: What if the package name is different?.. instead of x.y.z what if it is x.y.z.p.q?.. I am merely curious about your approach.

Comment: I don't have packages like x.y.z.p.q. I have packages only like x.y.z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
String[] str = line.split("((?<=.*\\..*\\..*)\\.|=)");
```

This split on a `.` with at least two `.` before, and on `=`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*)\\.(.*)\\.(.*)=(.*)$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("com.mgnt.util.DateTimeTokenizer.setEndDateTimeValues=90027");

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
    }
```

Result

```
com.mgnt.util
DateTimeTokenizer
setEndDateTimeValues
90027
```

Comment: \S instead of "." if you don't want to have whitespaces in your String